# Why is WSGIScriptAlias not having an effect?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, apache2, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I'm running into an issue with setting a WSGIScriptAlias in Apache, where attempting to use the alias is giving a 404 error due to trying to reach the "literal" URL. Here's the test set-up in my Apache2 `sites-available/000-default.conf` (mimicking the [mod_wsgi Quick Start Guide](http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/quick-configuration-guide.html)):

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
WSGIScriptAlias /wsgi_test /var/www/html/test.wsgi
<Directory /var/www/html>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

After restarting Apache2 and going to `mydomain.com/wsgi_test`, a 404 page is displayed. The first line of Apache's `error.log` file below shows the server attempting to access the URL path `wsgi_test` in `DocumentRoot`, not the aliased file path:

```
AH00128: File does not exist: /var/www/html/wsgi_test
AH01964: Connection to child 1 established (server nathanclonts.com:443)
(70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 67.161.148.188:33883] AH01991: SSL input filter read failed.
```

The file `/var/www/html/test.wsgi` has the same code as the above-mentioned Quick Start Guide:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    output = b'Hello World!'
    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                    ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)
    return [output]
```

With permissions set to:

```
-rwxrw-r-- 1 username www-data   278 Apr 16 11:31 test.wsgi
```

Does anyone have suggestions on where to look for other configuration that may be affecting this, or any other debugging tips?

What's odd is that I have set up another (Django) application with mod_wsgi that is currently working in the same VirtualHost, but obviously I'm missing something in this test.

Comment: Where is the Django configuration defined relative to what you added? If the Django application is at path of '/', then what you add here must be before that, else the matching of '/' for the Django application will take precedence.

Comment: It turns out that it was just a problem with the general Alias configuration: the [WSGIScript]Aliases were defined for `VirtualHost *`, but not for `VirtualHost *:433` (the server uses SSL). Adding them to the `VirtualHost *:433 file fixed it. Thanks for the suggestion though, good thing to keep in mind!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by updating the `<VirtualHost *:443>` configuration file to include the `WSGIScriptAlias` line (as the server uses SSL), instead of having `WSGIScriptAlias` under the `<VirtualHost *>` configuration.

I wasn't aware that all Aliases needed to be included in the 443 port to function, but eventually worked it out after playing with a vanilla `Alias` and locating which files they were defined in with:

```
grep -R "Alias" /etc/apache2/*
```